# How to remove header for notes in Enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Could someone please help me removing "notes" header for notes from the element displayed on a diagram? I mean the actual word: "notes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you mean the "notes" header that is shown in the notes compartment of the element if you check the "show notes" checkbox in the "Feature and Compartment Visibility" dialog?
I'm afraid you won't be able to remove that, unless you write a shapescript to duplicate the default shape minus the "notes" header.

Another option might be to create a note element on the diagram and link that to the elements notes using "Link Note  to element feature"
Additional advantage of this approach is that you can keep the text formatting in the note element, which is lost in the element compartment.

Comment: Hi Geert, that solution with "link note to element" is great idea, but it seems the only way to do it is first display notes on the diagram and only then by clicking on element notes I can create linked note. When I select element (without notes displayed) and go to Element > Inline features, Create Linked note is not available... am I missing something?

Comment: @Macin I added the element on the diagram, then added the note and linked it to the element. Then on the link between the note and the element I choose link to element feature.

Comment: I followed your suggestions and managed to achieve the result I needed, so thank you once again.

Comment: @Macin What did you end up doing? Recreate the shapes? If so, is there an easy way to do that (e.g., did you find the original shape files somewhere?